# Error when running a simple pynput program

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm making a project and a part of it is making a program that when activated, automatically right clicks whenever I left click. But when I launch the program and left click, it returns an error:
`TypeError: combatModules.on_click() takes 4 positional arguments but 5 were given`
My code: (I'm using threads so i can have multiple programs running at once from the same program.)

```
import pydirectinput as pa
import time as t
import pynput
import threading
class combatModules:
    def __init__(self) -> None:
        pass
    
    def on_click(x, y, button, pressed):
        if button == pynput.mouse.Button.left:
            print('{} at {}'.format('Pressed Left Click' if pressed else 'Released Left Click', (x, y)))
            pa.rightClick()
        else:
            print('{} at {}'.format('Pressed Right Click' if pressed else 'Released Right Click', (x, y)))
        
    def blockHitCode(self):
        for i in range(100):
            listener = pynput.mouse.Listener(on_click=self.on_click)
            listener.start()
            listener.join()
    def blockHit(self):
        blockHitThread = threading.Thread(target=self.blockHitCode)
        blockHitThread.start()
```

A little explanation: blockHit() is meant to be executed from the main program.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your method is missing the `self` argument. This is required for methods in a class like you have with the `blockHitCode` and `blockHit`.

This should fix the error you are having:

`def on_click(self, x, y, button, pressed):`